# Need to do calculation in dataframe with previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame with two column. The condition I need to form is when 'Balance Created column is empty, I need to take last filled value of Balance Created and add it with the next row of Amount value.

Original Data frame:

[image]

After Calculation, my desired result should be:

[image]

Comment: `df['Amount'].cumsum()`, you can use this, a cummulative sum of other column, please explore documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using cummulative sum of pandas to achieve this,

```
df['Amount'].cumsum()

# Edit-1
condition = df['Balance Created'].isnull()
df.loc[condition, 'Balance Created'] = df['Amount'].loc[condition]
```

you can also apply based on groups like deposit and withdraw

```
df.groupby('transaction')['Amount'].cumsum()
```

Comment: this cumsum apply on whole Amount column, what i need to do is to start only when the balance created value is null. How can i achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you mind adding as small snippet with 4 to 5 rows, bit clarity needed :-| @MojizMehdi

Comment: Edited my question with adding 'nan', hope it helps. I just need to ignore already filled data in balance created column and then applying something like cumsum in blank cells

Comment: Need to start cumsum function from index 4 in dataframe

Comment: actually, data mismatch is not happening with the cumsum, shall we take this direct column assignment `df['Balance Created'] = df['Amount'].cumsum() `,

Comment: I know data is not mismatching with this example, but the already filled data is coming from some other source, and I have to keep the error room in it. Since i have to other calculations and check as well, I can't apply cumsum to the whole column. Hope you'd understand the requirement now.

Comment: got it ,  # Edit-1 code, wont disturb the filled data, you can check once

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is mostly "How do I solve this using pandas", which is a good question that others have given you pandas-specific answers for.

But in case this question is more in the lines of "How do I solve this using an algorithm", which is a common problem to solve for people just starting of writing code, then this little paragraph might push you in the right direction.

```
for index in frame do 
  if frame.balance[i] is empty do 
    if i equals 0 do // Edge-case where first balance is missing
      frame.balance[i] = frame.amount[i]
    else do
      frame.balance[i] = frame.amount[i] + frame.balance[i-1]
    end
  end
end
```